# Well-definedness of complex $\sin^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

I am define the inverse of complex $\sin$. I know that $\sin$ the conformal map mapping the strip $\{(x,y):x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2), y>0\}$ to the upper half plane as the composition of the conformal maps $e^{iz}$ and $\frac{z-1/z}{2i}$. I am trying to find the inverse. I think $\int_0^z \frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$ should play the role where the integral is over any contour from 0 to z and the branch for the square is $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$. Since $\sin^{-1}x=\int_0^x \frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$
when $x\in[-1,1]$.

I am trying to use the analytic continuation. But I encountered some problems:

1. $sin$ is the conformal map between the strip and the upper half plane, so its existence is guaranteed only on the upper half plane but not the real line. So I cannot use the analytic continuation directly from the fact that $\sin^{-1}x=\int_0^x \frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$
   when $x\in[-1,1]$.
2. The behaviour of $\int_0^z \frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$ on the real line. I think $\int_0^z \frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$ is well-defined at $+1,-1$ even $\frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}$ has singularity at $+1,-1$, since $\int_0^1 1/s^{\beta} <\infty$ whenever $\beta<1$. But I do not know how to write down the argument for $\int_0^1 |\frac{1}{{(1-s^2})^{1/2}}|$ is finite on any contour connecting $0$ and $1$. Or more fundamentally, I do not know how to write down the rigorous argument for $\int_a^b |\frac{1}{z(t)^{1/2}}z'(t)|\le M\int_a^b |\frac{1}{z(t)^{1/2}}|<\infty$ where $z$ is the a contour from $0$ to $z$ in the upper half plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the inverse of the restriction of $\sin$ to the whole vertical strip$$\left\{z\in\Bbb C\,\middle|\,\operatorname{Re}(z)\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)\right\}.$$ Then\begin{align}a'(z)&=\left(\sin^{-1}\right)'(z)\\&=\frac1{\cos(a(z))}\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}\left(a'(z)\right)^2&=\frac1{\cos^2(a(z))}\\&=\frac1{1-\sin^2(a(z))}\\&=\frac1{1-z^2}.\end{align}Now, let $h(z)=\frac1{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}$, where, for each $z\in\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, $z^{1/2}$ is the only square root of $z$ such that $\operatorname{Re}\left(z^{1/2}\right)>0$. It follows from what was done above that $(a')^2=h^2$ and that therefore $(a'-h)(a'+h)=0$. So, since we are dealing with analytic functions here, $a'=h$ or $a'=-h$. But we cannot have $a'=-h$, since $a'(0)=h'(0)=1$. So, $a'=h$ and therefore $a$ is the only primitive of $h$ which maps $0$ into $0$. In other words,$$a(z)=\int_{[0,z]}\frac1{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}\,\mathrm dz,$$where $[0,z]\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is the path defined by $[0,z](t)=tz$. Still in other words,$$a(z)=\int_0^1\frac z{(1-z^2t^2)^{1/2}}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: Why we can choose the specific contour $tz?$ $(1-z^2)^{1/2}$ is holomorphic only on $\mathbb C \setminus \{1\}$. So $\int (1-z^2)^1/2$ is only independent of path on $\mathbb C\setminus \{1\}$ by Cauchy's Theorem? But here the path is connecting $1$.

Comment: I don't understand most of what you wrote. I chose $t\mapsto tz$ because it was a natural choice of a path from $0$ into $z$. The function $z\mapsto(1-z^2)^{1/2}$ is holomorphic on the strip, which is simply connected. So, *any* path going from $0$ to $z$ (within the strip) would have worked, And I have no clue about the meaning of “here the path is connecting $1$”.

Comment: Sorry it should be $(1−z^2)^{-1/2}$ is not holomorphic at 1. Or by any branch, I think  $(1−z^2)^{1/2}$ is still not holomorphic at $1$. Since $z^1/2$ is not holomorphic at 0. For $\int_0^1 (1−z^2)^{-1/2}$, you are taking the specific path $t\to t$ on $[0,1]$. What I was asking is why $\int_0^1 (1−z^2)^{-1/2}$ independent of which path connecting $0$ and $1$.i.e will the integration still be the same if we take different path.

Comment: The function $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$ is *undefined* at $1$, and therefore it is neither holomorphic nor non-holomorphic there. Would you please explain what's your problem with the point $1$? Since it does not belong to the domain of $a$ (and it doesn't belong to the domain of $a$ because it doesn't belong to the range of restriction of $\sin$ to the strip), I really don't see why you bother with it. And please forget the “(within the strip)” from my previous comment. The strip is not the domain of $a$.

Comment: I was considering $sin$ as the conformal map between $\{(x,y):x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2), y>0\}$ and the upper-half plane. And I want to see the boundary behaviour. But anyway, my question is mainly about the finiteness of $|\int _0^z 1/s^{\beta}|\le \int_a^b 1/|s(t)|^\beta |s'(t)|$ when $0<\beta<1$ and $z$ is any point in the complex plane except $0$ and $s$ is a contour connecting $0$ and $z$. I know $\int _0^x 1/s^{\beta}<\infty$

Comment: I guess I found the answer myself. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am also wondering what is the image of the restriction of $sin$ to the strip you written in your answer.

Comment: It's $\Bbb C\setminus\bigl((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)\bigr)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.